# Should be in Decimal form

Tags: java

My program should work only if you input a decimal number. But when I enter a whole number it still run. need help

```
import java.util.*;

public class Welcome{

       public void CelFar(){

         Scanner decimal = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");

         try{ 


             double value = decimal.nextDouble();
             value = ((value - 32)*5)/9;

             System.out.println("RESULT : " +value);


            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Must be in decimal number ! ");
            }


        }


    }
```

Comment: A number without a decimal point has the same value as if you're add `.0` to it. Why is this a problem?

Comment: My program must run in decimal value only. example if you enter a whole number. there must a an error. what code should be

Comment: @JoeC My program must run in decimal value only. example if you enter a whole number. there must a an error. what code should be

Comment: @Simba Just throwing this out there... why exactly do you want an error in that case?

Comment: Is 1.0 a whole number?

Comment: Define 'decimal form'. Do you mean it should have a fractional part?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completelly clear to me what do you want to achieve:

1. should the program return error if the input value is 1.0 for example?
2. should the program return error if the input value is 1, but if it's 1.0 is ok?

if answer is (1) i would just validate if returned decimal can be converted to int or  (without losing precision).
if answer is (2) (it seems so) i would just use scanner.next(), which returns String, instead of nextDouble(). then validate if String can be converted to int or not before actually converting to double.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want `42` to be an error, but `42.0` to be acceptable, even though they are both exactly the same number, verify the input first, by calling the `hasNextXxx` methods.

That also fixes your problem of using exception to catch bad input.

```
Scanner decimal = new Scanner(System.in);
for (;;) { // forever loop
    System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
    if (decimal.hasNextDouble() && ! decimal.hasNextBigInteger()) {
        double value = decimal.nextDouble();
        value = ((value - 32)*5)/9;
        System.out.println("RESULT : " +value);
        break; // exit forever loop
    }
    decimal.next(); // consume bad token
    System.out.println("Must be in decimal number ! ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work your program as only for decimals, then you can try one hack,

1- you can convert your number to string

2- split string by using decimal character

3- Convert string after decimal in to number and find whether it is greater than 0 or not

4- if it is greater than 0 then it is decimal number and then perform the action

5- if not then it a whole number  and throw exception